# On editing task list item creates duplicate/triplicate item

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, task-list, duplicate

I added the task list as an app-part to a page.

When I edit an item, on save it creates a duplicate item just like when we "Save as" any document.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you use InfoPath form? Any customizations in the form? Is there a workflow associated to the list item to create a copy when the item is changed? Provide more information about your task list.

Comment: It is a default form of SharePoint for editing an item.
There is no workflow to create a copy when the item changes , however there are other workflows running on the task list for processing the task for approval, etc.

Comment: you click the save button only once?

Comment: Yes, even If I click the save button only once it duplicates.